# ROS_WARN not able to print std::string

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I want to print in a ROS WARNING a string. But I am not able to do that.

Someone of you could help me please?

What I am doing is the following:

> std::string topicNameTrajInput ="TopicRos";
>
> ROS_WARN(topicNameTrajInput);

Any ideas why this doesn't work?
Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201048/ros_warn-not-able-to-print-std::string/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ROS_WARN` behaves like `printf` so for a `std::string` it'd be something like:

```
ROS_WARN( "%s", topicNameTrajInput.c_str() ); // (Format string and args for the format string)
```

I'd suggest use use the easier `ROS_WARM_STREAM` for a `std::string`, it behaves like `std::cout`, e. g.:

```
ROS_WARN_STREAM( topicNameTrajInput );
```

or with << operator and multiple args :

```
ROS_WARN_STREAM( topicNameTrajInput << " Hello world " << 1000 );
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8